# Can we make all elements equal using the mentioned operations any number of times?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

Given a sequence of positive integers of length $n$. In one operation, we can pick any two elements from the sequence and multiply the first by $2$ and add $1$ to the second. Can we make the sequence equal by doing the allowed operation any number of times (possible zero)?

Examples

$[11, 5, 6]$, answer is "YES",

Multiply $6$ by $2$ and add $1$ to $5$ which leads to $[11, 6, 12]$.

then

Multiply $6$ by $2$ and add $1$ to $11$ which leads to $[12, 12, 12]$.

I believe for $n \leq  2$, the answer is "YES".

For example $[2, 4]$, we can do the following sequence of operations.

$[2, 4] \rightarrow [3, 8] \rightarrow [4, 16] \rightarrow [8, 17] \rightarrow [9, 34] \rightarrow [18, 35] \rightarrow [36, 36]$.

Is the answer always YES for any sequence of length  $n$  of positive integers?